# error in modify pom with jenkins in Jenkinsfile

Tags: maven, jenkins, pom.xml, jenkins-pipeline

in Jenkinsfile, i want to add reporting config by modify pom.xml:

```
def pom = readMavenPom file: 'pom.xml'
reporting = new org.apache.maven.model.Reporting();
def reportPlugin =  new ReportPlugin();
reportPlugin.setGroupId('org.apache.maven.plugins');
....
pom.setReporting(reporting);
```

then error report:

```
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.apache.maven.model.Model.setReporting() is applicable for argument types: (org.apache.maven.model.Reporting) values: [org.apache.maven.model.Reporting@5ef6c603]
Possible solutions: setReporting(org.apache.maven.model.Reporting), getReporting(), setReports(java.lang.Object), getReports()
The following classes appear as argument class and as parameter class, but are defined by different class loader:
org.apache.maven.model.Reporting (defined by 'AntClassLoader[/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/aether-api-1.1.0.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/aether-connector-basic-1.1.0.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/aether-impl-1.1.0.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/aether-spi-1.1.0.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/aether-transport-wagon-1.1.0.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/aether-util-1.1.0.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/ant-1.9.2.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/ant-launcher-1.9.2.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/cdi-api-1.0.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/commons-io-2.5.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/commons-net-3.5.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/doxia-sink-api-1.0.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/findbugs-annotations-1.3.9-1.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/jackrabbit-webdav-2.14.1.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/jna-platform-4.1.0.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/jsch.agentproxy.connector-factory-0.0.9.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/jsch.agentproxy.core-0.0.9.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/jsch.agentproxy.jsch-0.0.9.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/jsch.agentproxy.pageant-0.0.9.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/jsch.agentproxy.sshagent-0.0.9.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/jsch.agentproxy.usocket-jna-0.0.9.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/jsch.agentproxy.usocket-nc-0.0.9.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/jsoup-1.7.2.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/jsr250-api-1.0.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/lib-jenkins-maven-artifact-manager-1.2.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/lib-jenkins-maven-embedder-3.12.1.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven-aether-provider-3.1.0.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven-agent-1.12-alpha-1.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven-artifact-3.1.0.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven-compat-3.1.0.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven-core-3.1.0.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven-embedder-3.1.0.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven-interceptor-1.12-alpha-1.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven-model-3.1.0.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven-model-builder-3.1.0.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven-plugin-api-3.1.0.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven-plugin.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven-reporting-api-3.0.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven-repository-metadata-3.5.0.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven-settings-3.1.0.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven-settings-builder-3.1.0.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven2.1-interceptor-1.2.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-agent-1.12-alpha-1.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-1.12-alpha-1.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-commons-1.12-alpha-1.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven31-agent-1.12-alpha-1.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven31-interceptor-1.12-alpha-1.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven32-agent-1.12-alpha-1.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven32-interceptor-1.12-alpha-1.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven33-agent-1.12-alpha-1.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven33-interceptor-1.12-alpha-1.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven35-agent-1.12-alpha-1.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven35-interceptor-1.12-alpha-1.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/org.eclipse.sisu.inject-0.3.3.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/org.eclipse.sisu.plexus-0.3.3.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/plexus-cipher-1.7.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/plexus-component-annotations-1.7.1.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/plexus-interactivity-api-1.0-alpha-6.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/plexus-interpolation-1.16.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/plexus-utils-3.0.24.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/wagon-file-3.0.0.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/wagon-ftp-3.0.0.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/wagon-http-3.0.0.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/wagon-http-shared-3.0.0.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/wagon-provider-api-3.0.0.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/wagon-ssh-3.0.0.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/wagon-ssh-common-3.0.0.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/wagon-ssh-external-3.0.0.jar:/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/wagon-webdav-jackrabbit-3.0.0.jar]' and 'AntClassLoader[/jenkins/plugins/pipeline-utility-steps/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-utility-steps.jar:/jenkins/plugins/pipeline-utility-steps/WEB-INF/lib/plexus-utils-3.0.22.jar:/jenkins/plugins/pipeline-utility-steps/WEB-INF/lib/commons-lang3-3.4.jar:/jenkins/plugins/pipeline-utility-steps/WEB-INF/lib/maven-model-3.3.9.jar]')
If one of the method suggestions matches the method you wanted to call,
    then check your class loader setup.
```

does anyone know what the issue is?

Comment: Why not directly changing the pom file and checkin the result...?What is the problem you are trying to resolve?

Comment: thanks for your reply.

Comment: there is 40+project, i dont want to change every project, so, i installed the Pipeline Utility Steps plugin and then modify the pom after download the code in Jenckins file.

Comment: Using a parent is the usual solution. Furthermore this will not work, cause you can't write back the correct pom files and in consequence your are building something different than what is in your version control.